# Wiredep says Bower packages are not installed

Tags: visual-studio, npm, gulp, bower, asp.net-core

I have the following `wiredep` task:

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
    log('Installing Bower Components in HTML files...)
    return gulp
        .src('./Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            bowerJson: require('./bower.json'),
            directory: './bower_components/',
            ignorePath: '../..'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

The goal is to convert the

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endbower -->
```

to actual JavaScripts as specified in my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.0.0",
    "hammer.js": "2.0.4",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "knockout": "3.3.0"
  }
}
```

When I run the task I get the following output:

```
[15:53:06] Starting 'wiredep'...
[15:53:06] Installing Bower Components in HTML files...
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Error: bootstrap is not installed. Try running `bower install` or remove the component from your bower.json file
```

I do see the packages in wwwroot/lib, so I think Bower is actually installing it.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this part of your script:

directory: './bower_components/',

is using the wrong path /bower_components/ is the default install folder for bower components (actually in beta 4 VS 2015 RC it used to put files there) but in the latest VS project template there is a file .bowerrc in the root of the app that tells it to put bower components under wwwroot/lib instead of the default folder name. so directory needs to be ./wwwroot/lib/' I think.

Comment: Hi Joe! :-) Thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: Joe, this solves the specific issue in the question. However, it still does not work properly since, although it says the _Layout page has changed, the components are not there.

Comment: sorry I don't know what wiredep is or what it is supposed to do, maybe someone else can help with that one

Comment: I had to properly specify the end path in destination. :-) It was at the wrong position. Wiredep automatically injects your bower components in the right order in your lay-out page if you specify a placeholder there. That way you don't have to copy add the references to stylesheets and javascripts there once you install a new package. Thanks for your help!

Comment: that doesn't sound like something I would want to use. some bower stuff I would use a cdn in production and others I might combine into bundles. as mentioned previously _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml was very enlightening for me about how to add my scripts. or even the standard _Layout.cshtml from the latest project template shows how to use bootstrap from cdn on production and local bower files in dev.

Comment: Good points. You can actually combine them as well before injecting by using Usemin. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322326/combine-and-minify-all-bower-libraries-with-gruntjs. Or using a CDN can perhaps be done by replacing the generated bower outputs. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-google-cdn. Overall I think it can be very handy. You don't have to worry about the order anymore and they are automatically added.